# Concatenation not working on arguments of function

Tags: javascript, jsx

I need to concat two values to pass them as argument on the Y axis value of my plot. I was able to concat them but when I pass it to my 'y' value it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?
This code work:

```
switch (statement) {
        //CashFlow
        case 'changeInOperatingLiabilities':
                return (        
            <Fragment><Plot data={[{type: 'bar', x: financialItem.fiscalDateEndingValues, y: financialItem.changeInOperatingLiabilitiesValues},]}
            layout={{width: 900, height: 640, title: financialItemName}} options ={ {displaylogo: 'false'} }/></Fragment>
        );
```

This code doesn't work:

```
switch (statement) {
        //CashFlow
        case 'changeInOperatingLiabilities':
                return (        
            <Fragment><Plot data={[{type: 'bar', x: financialItem.fiscalDateEndingValues, y:''.concat('financialItem.',statement,'Values')},]}
            layout={{width: 900, height: 640, title: financialItemName}} options ={ {displaylogo: 'false'} }/></Fragment>
        );
```

`console.log(''.concat('financialItem.',statement,'Values'))` returns exactly what I expected:
financialItem.changeInOperatingLiabilitiesValues

I'm trying to do this because my switch is getting too long.
Thanks very much for helping

Comment: When you use `concat()` it returns a string not the that string's value if its the same with a variable name. 
Are you expecting the variable's value?

Comment: I'm assuming your `x` and `y` fields are expecting functions, and the result of a `.concat()` is a string. You probably don't even need the switch statement if you do: `y: financialItem[\`${statment}Values\`]`.

Comment: Yes exactly I don't need a string value but a variable with that name, so I'm expecting the variable's value. Ghassen Louhaichi solution did the job. Thank you very much